# What type of issues does Sony FR7 have with NDI?

Tags: video-quality, streaming, broadcasting, zoom, sony

What issues does Sony have, if any, with the NDI protocol?
Is the image as good if it was recorded in camera?

I appreciate any help you can provide.

Here is a list of the items Im researching

- Sony FR7
- Sony FE 16-35MM
- NDI License (maybe)
- Tricaster Mini 4k (maybe with HDMI or the NDI option)
- Netgear GMS4212UX // M4250-10G2XF-POE++